# ¿Cómo accedo a clases de otros paquetes en Java?

Tags: java

Lo que quiero hacer es acceder a la información de mi otro paquete donde tengo una clase que necesito, anteriormente funcionaba porque estaba dentro de el mismo paquete, pero ahora que lo he separado me sale el siguiente error:

> connection is not public in Conexion_BD; cannot be accessed from
>   outside package

La clase que mando llamar es la siguiente:

```
public class Conexion_BD {

    Connection connection = null;

    public void conectar() throws ClassNotFoundException {

        try {
             connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/archivo", "root", "");

        } catch (SQLException e) {
             System.out.println("La Conexion a la Base de datos fallo.");
             e.printStackTrace();
             return;
        } 

    }
}
```

Para poder acceder a dicha clase lo intento de la siguiente forma:

```
import BD.Conexion_BD;

BD.Conexion_BD conectar = new BD.Conexion_BD();

public PintarFrame() throws ClassNotFoundException {
    conectar.conectar();
}

Statement st = conectar.connection.createStatement(); --- Aquí esta el Error
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

El error que estás teniendo es que no puedes acceder a tu variable `Connection connection = null;` y al utilizarla te está dando ese problema.

Modifica tu código de la siguiente forma:

```
private Connection connection = null;

public Connection getConnection(){
     return connection ;
}
```

Y para acceder a la variable:

```
Statement st = conectar.getConnection().createStatement();
```

luego haz un clean y rebuild del proyecto para que los cambios estén presentes

Comment: No recomendaría poner public variables, no es buena práctica por el principio de encapsulamiento. Sería mejor que sea private y tener un public Connection getConnection()...

Comment: @DiegoMartin es verdad lo que dices, no me he dado cuenta, voy a modificar mi respuesta